# Is it possible to have rounded window corners in Kubuntu 18.04?

Tags: kubuntu, themes

I have seen screenshots of Gnome-based desktops with rounded window corners, which I quite like the look of, so I am wondering if it is possible in Kubuntu 18.04, preferably only using the standard themes/repositories?

Comment: I think not yet, not with the standard themes. See https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/comments/g1mlig/a_bunch_of_suggestions_and_feedback_part_2/

Comment: @DKBose thank you, interesting discussion which points to the short answer to my question being "no"! But it's not a big deal, I started with default Ubuntu and switched to Kubuntu and never looked back.

Comment: And the situation won't change in Kubuntu 20.04. KDE neon and Kubuntu interim releases such as those after 20.04 but before the next LTS probably will have a backports ppa to give users the latest Plasma version. One constraint, which I can't explain, is that Kubuntu, even with the backports ppa, will likely not have the `qt` version that KDE neon and rolling release distros provide. How this will affect Kubuntu is something I don't know.

Comment: Soemthing to look at: [Rounded Plasma and Qt CSDs?](https://psifidotos.blogspot.com/2020/04/article-rounded-plasma-and-qt-csds.html)

Comment: @DKBose thanks I did find that rounded theme and it worked for plasma menus and widget-related things, but not main app windows, so I concluded my expectations were too great!  :-D

Comment: Check this: https://github.com/alex47/KDE-Rounded-Corners

Comment: @omerfarukdogan nice find, thank you!